# How to escape a query in Sitecore PowerShell

Tags: powershell-extensions

This PowerShell query breaks, if the item name contains query operators such as "and" or "child".
How should I escape it, so that they don't break it?

```
$SourceItemPath = $SourceItem.Paths.path
$SourceAncestorItem = Get-Item -Path "master:" -Query "$SourceItemPath/ancestor-or-self::*[@@templatekey='my template key']"
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the name in `# #`. This would likely be an issue with the Sitecore API rather than SPE, consider verifying with documentation supporting the query format.

Comment: Yes, I used Dmytro's answer, which worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Sitecore Query, you escape keywords and whitespaces by surrounding path parts with hashes.

To make your query work, prepare the path like this:

```
$SourceItemPath = $SourceItemPath -replace '[^/]*(and|or|child|descendant|\s)[^/]*','#$&#'
```

This will convert `/some/path/bla and bla/something` to `/some/path/#bla and bla#/something`

Comment: Thanks, that works a treat, though I'm not a fan of regular expressions (find them too opaque). I was hoping I'd just missed a syntax trick.

Comment: Added a link to this question in the SPE Gitbook.