# How to automatically escape item paths for use in Sitecore query

Tags: sitecore-api, sitecore-query

Is there some API utility method which can automatically escape an item path for use in a Sitecore query?

I am building a query string in code which uses an item path. If the item path contains a hyphen or underscore, then that name needs to be escaped in the query (surrounded by #) e.g.

```
/sitecore/content/my site/home/settings-folder
```

would need to be escaped to

```
/sitecore/content/my site/home/#settings folder#
```

I have code such as:

```
var query = $"{rootItem.Paths.FullPath}//*[@@templateid='{Templates.MyItemType.TemplateId}']";
var items = db.SelectItems(query);
```

This fails when the path has a hyphen `-` or underscore `_`. I've seen [this question related to SPE](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10127/how-to-escape-a-query-in-sitecore-powershell) so I could use that regex, but I wonder if there is already some utility method in the Sitecore API to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36991386/157833

Comment: Fortunately there are better and more efficient ways to get all descendant items of a certain template id that does not involve SlowQuery ;-)

Comment: I agree with @MarkCassidy, if you have code that's recursively getting all items of a certain template, you have much bigger issues than the hyphens.  That will never perform as well as the Content Search Api.

Comment: Open up the question to a broader/alternative solution answer and I'll be happy to add some thoughts :)

Comment: @MarkCassidy so just change the title, content and meaning of the question then... got it ;-)